# Parsing xml with unbound prefixes

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, sax

Trying to SAX parse

```
<foo bar:car="zoo"/>
```

Results in:

```
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 1 of document file:///c:/temp/test.xml : The prefix "bar" for attribute "bar:car" associated with an element type "foo" is not bound. Nested exception: The prefix "bar" for attribute "bar:car" associated with an element type "foo" is not bound.
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
        at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:321)
        at .<init>(<console>:18)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
        at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja...
```

How can I work around that without changing the XML? (The real XML comes from a web service I have no control over)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disable `http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces`:

```
xmlReader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
```

This will prevent the conversion of namespace prefixes into URIs.

Comment: It doens't work.
I've tried to copy the code from org.dom4j.Document dom4jDoc = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);
and put
   reader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
but the result is the same:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "xx" for element "xx:service" is not bound.
 at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)

I agree that xml should have the namespace declared but it's not in my control and it's very short.

Comment: @Uberto not all XMLReaders support setting that feature to false. You may also be setting it in the wrong context. To debug, try seeing if the feature was actually true before your call and has actually been set to false after it. Also check its value just before reading the element/attribute where you're getting the unwanted namespace error.